# How to change fonts using revealjs_presentation of R Markdown?

Tags: css, r-markdown, knitr, reveal.js

I would like to use [Noto Sans JP](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP), or also called [Source Han Serif OTF Japanese](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/tree/release/OTF/Japanese), in my presentation made with `revealjs_presentation` of R Markdown. The image below will tell you the shape of the font.

[image: Noto Sans JP, or Source Han Serif OTF Japanese]

Since Google provides a [css of the font](https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansjapanese.css), I put its URL into `output: revealjs::revealjs_presentation: css` in the YAML section. However, `knitr` still produces HTML slides using the default fonts, as shown below. Then, how should I specify the font when I want to get HTML slides using R Markdown?

[image]

## What I've tried (MWE)

````
---
title: |
  | タイトル
subtitle: |
  | <small> テスト </small>
author: | 
  | @CLRafaelR
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y年 %B %e日')`"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    css: https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansjapanese.css
    self_contained: true
---

# R Markdown

あいうえお

## R Markdown

これはRマークダウンのプレゼンテーションです。
マークダウンとは、HTML、PDF、MS Wordの書類を作成する際に使える簡単な記法です。
R Markdownに関する詳細は、<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>をご覧ください。

This is an R Markdown presentation.
Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. 
For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.


## Slide with Bullets

あいうえお

- 甲
- 乙
- 丙

> - 丁
> - 戊
> - 己

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

## Note

Actually, I have the otf files of [`Source Han Sans`](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif/tree/release/OTF/Japanese) under the following path. Is there way to call the local font path in R Markdown?

`C:/Users/my-true-user-name/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts`

## `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Japanese_Japan.932  LC_CTYPE=Japanese_Japan.932    LC_MONETARY=Japanese_Japan.932
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Japanese_Japan.932    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.2   rsconnect_0.8.16 htmltools_0.4.0  tools_3.6.2      revealjs_0.9     yaml_2.2.1      
 [7] Rcpp_1.0.3       rmarkdown_2.1    knitr_1.28       xfun_0.12        digest_0.6.25    packrat_0.5.0   
[13] rlang_0.4.4      evaluate_0.14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was on the [Google Fonts' Noto Sans JP page](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP?selection.family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&sidebar.open)...
It's just to copy the following codes and to paste them on the non-YAML part of the Rmd file.

[image]

## Definitive MWE

````
---
title: |
  | タイトル
subtitle: |
  | <small> テスト </small>
author: | 
  | @CLRafaelR
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y年 %B %e日')`"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: true
---

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
</style>

```{css css-settings, echo=FALSE}
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.reveal .slide {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}
```


# R Markdown

あいうえお

## R Markdown

これはRマークダウンのプレゼンテーションです。
マークダウンとは、HTML、PDF、MS Wordの書類を作成する際に使える簡単な記法です。R Markdownに関する詳細は、<http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>をご覧ください。

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

## Slide with Bullets

あいうえお

- 甲
- 乙
- 丙

> - 丁
> - 戊
> - 己

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````